# How to clean or refresh ImageView bitMap canvas?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view

The source code:

```
//The drawing of the circle on the canvas
imageView = new ImageView(this);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200 ,200 , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bitmap);
canvas.drawCircle (50 , 50 , 20 , paint );

.....
```

Now I want to refresh or to clean the canvas

How can I do it?

Comment: does `canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);` not work?

Comment: Hi Slayton, I try to write interactive application like MS Paint. I had this idea, but maybe there are exists the simpler way to refresh the canvas?

Comment: Hi again Slayton, when I think yet about your suggestion, it is a good and a simple idea. Please write your comment as an answer if you want that I'll mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting something... Wouldn't drawing the white rectangle over the canvas do the trick? Sorry if my comment is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Hi Ash, I think that it will work. I even didn't though in this direction. Maybe it has issue in bitmap size. For example, I think that bitmap with 20 small circles and 1 big rectangle has more size in bytes than bitmap with only 1 small circle (after creating new canvas). But I didn't tried to test it.

Comment: I don't think it is the case. Theoretically, memory for a bitmap should be allocated all at once, otherwise system would have to perform reallocations on almost every drawing operation.

Comment: Hi Ash, thanks for the comment, it looks right that you wrote, because we set bitmap configuration on its creation, and this is the actual size. So ,I think you are right also in you tricky idea. I'll try to test it and I'll update.

Comment: I've checked it with the following code: http://pastebin.com/d2cz4561 `getByteCount()` always returns the same result.

Comment: Ash, it is a great idea! it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Ash,I also tested it before and it worked. Now I saw your code , I took from there also  other nice idea : canvas.getHeight(). Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6903/discussion-between-ash-and-tatiana-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

Comment: When I test it now, I see that I still have the previous canvas' images. So I don't have a canvas cleaning. The idea that I had is to create other background for imageView, to recycle and create new bitmap and to set it again as background.